# How to add delay in autologin

Tags: linux, centos-6, auto-login

I enabled autologin in my system (CentOS 6.2)
for that I edited this file `/etc/gdm/custom.conf`
In that I entered this code

```
[daemon]
AutomaticLoginEnable=true
AutomaticLogin=test
```

Here test means one account name, for that account autologin is working but the problem is not possible to logout. That is because everytime while I logout it will go to gdm(graphical display manager) and there it Again checks for account test. It is available right so it will again login to same account.

Here I want add delay, that means it should wait for sometime, If no one login to any other account, then only test account will log.

how to add delay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change AutomaticLogin to TimedLogin.

```
TimedLoginEnable=true
TimedLogin=test
TimedLoginDelay=30
```